# Как убрать кусок убогого JSON-а?

Tags: json, golang

Всем привет! Один очень плохой сервис, условно назовем его "синева", в ответ на запрос, отдает мне вот такой **json**:

```
{"response":[6101,{"aid":416634748,"owner_id":8868604,"artist":"Басы сабвувер колонки клуб 1999 1998 1997 1996 кто родился в эти года ставь лайк порвёт сабвуху ","title":"Очень мощные тазы валят кавказ 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 лето все танцуем босиком зима весна осень новый год день рождения день победы качает кавказ азербайджан казахстан белоруссия украина россия трава героин амфетамин огурец помидор пельмени вареники ","duration":291,"url":"https:\/\/cs9-4v4.userapi.com\/p15\/fac0213f1dbfaf.mp3?extra=WFp4WVlKtQphdN1ZFBR1EXnQXFbF6mnjQnax-mOYAN1VUeyQVyZ23SgmA3lIZqUsD0ZAXTbkQt7oQzQymtlZDuQ2kwkd0kgJXZpRfGLHdT8qxegZBNVlPvBwlFCCmAv7bLCE7iQY_y0","lyrics_id":176912971,"genre":18},{"aid":65092529,"owner_id":-27906,"artist":"2h Company","title":"Огурец Мозга","duration":333,"url":"https:\/\/cs9-3v4.userapi.com\/p17\/cbd69519a82153.mp3?extra=5nY6SvOutPiei0V_fapIJMJ7AVOkdXNZKvFkg27HN4OPv254yly7_u2pUqYCXmqa0P4pXLMHKSctV4FYwzBLNSUOGV75r_uBftBb8F_e9isxk6UrVAUNIqlrrVut64vJqJohiW8r","lyrics_id":4062445,"album":1017155,"genre":18},{"aid":456298875,"owner_id":371745459,"artist":"2H Company","title":"Огурец мозга","duration":329,"url":"https:\/\/psv4.userapi.com\/c611117\/u371745459\/audios\/9bf0783fc243.mp3?extra=fZLOKdnGkb86CXC2Cmh686BZO9DBJmFdO-d0oiqfdr_7-igCNFDlJZLmbZIx6EP83xi_Z2w5S0xzOc9fP2bugccLVRtfa7ackSpdibBwcg4FgIjm0HdE3REahQdUKp1HNVUwIPGfGku8Yg"}]}
```

Распарсить его по-человечески в структуру невозможно из-за вот этого куска:

{"response"**:[6101,**{"aid":416634748,"o
Это дурацкое совершенно случайное число мешает критично просто. Из-за него я не могу получить такую красивую структуру, как эту:

```
    type AutoGenerated struct {
    Response []struct {
        Aid int `json:"aid"`
        OwnerID int `json:"owner_id"`
        Artist string `json:"artist"`
        Title string `json:"title"`
        Duration int `json:"duration"`
        URL string `json:"url"`
        LyricsID int `json:"lyrics_id,omitempty"`
        Genre int `json:"genre,omitempty"`
        Album int `json:"album,omitempty"`
    } `json:"response"`
}
```

Возможно, кто-то предложит хоть более-менее адекватный вариант удаления этого числа?
**p/s** заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Используйте последнюю версию API этой "синевы", и число пропадёт само

Comment: И оно не случайное, а содержит общее число доступных аудиозаписей, соответствующих вашему запросу к "синеве"

Comment: Андрей, Вы действительно правы :) Теперь это число адекватное... Класс! Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal ааа, а разве эта "синева"))) не закрыла доступ к аудиозаписям еще в конце прошлого года?

Comment: ну, для кого закрыла, а кто и доки по новым методам собрал :D Я блин только ступил, знал же, что 5.65 ласт версия, но нет, даже не проверил  дурацкий count...

Answer (score 0):

регулярные выражения вам в помощь, если используете Golang, прогоните этот кусок через:

```
json.replaceAll('/^\{\"response\"\:\[[\d]+\,/iu', '{"response":[');
```

как понимаю, надо убрать только число с запятой?

Comment: там же тег стоит: golang :)

Comment: да, не сразу заметил, отредактировал

Comment: @Flerry используйте функцию ReplaceAll() с указанными регулярными выражениями.

Comment: такой функции нет

Comment: посмотрите эти ссылки:

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAll

Comment: благодарю, сейчас гляну...